# loop through a r dataframe and pass rows as parameters to a function

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I want to loop through a dataframe and pass the rows as arguments to a function to summarise the totals from a dataframe named df3.

I have tried code using a traditional for loop but there are not results.

I have looked at pmap in https://adv-r.hadley.nz/functionals.html#pmap

but the I don't see how to apply this example to my code.

Here is some data from the original data:

```
dput(head(df3,n=3))
structure(list(id = c("81", "83", "85"), look_work = c("yes", 
"yes", "yes"), current_work = c("no", "yes", "no"), hf_l5k = c("", 
"", ""), ac_l5k = c("", "", ""), hf_5_10k = c("", "1", "1"), 
    ac_5_10k = c("", "1", "1"), hf_11_20k = c("", "", ""), ac_11_20k = c("", 
    "", ""), hf_21_50k = c("", "", ""), ac_21_50k = c("", "", 
    ""), hf_51_100k = c("", "", ""), ac_51_100k = c("", "", ""
    ), hf_m100k = c("", "", ""), ac_m100k = c("", "", ""), s_l1000 = c("", 
    "", ""), se_l1000 = c("", "", "1"), s_1001_1500 = c("", "1", 
    "1"), se_1001_1500 = c("", "", ""), s_2001_3000 = c("", "", 
    ""), se_2001_3000 = c("", "1", ""), s_3001_4000 = c("", "", 
    ""), se_3001_4000 = c("", "", ""), s_4001_5000 = c("", "", 
    ""), se_4001_5000 = c("", "", ""), s_5001_6000 = c("", "", 
    ""), se_5001_6000 = c("", "", ""), s_m6000 = c("", "", ""
    ), se_m6000 = c("", "", ""), s_n_ans = c("", "", ""), se_n_ans = c("", 
    "", ""), before_work = c("no", "NULL", "yes"), keen_move = c("yes", 
    "yes", "no"), city_size = c("village", "more than 500k inhabitants", 
    "more than 500k inhabitants"), gender = c("male", "female", 
    "female"), age = c("18 - 24 years", "18 - 24 years", "more than 50 years"
    ), education = c("secondary", "vocational", "secondary")), row.names = c(NA, 
3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Here is the dataframe hf_names for the parameters:

```
structure(list(hf_names = c("hf_l5k", "hf_5_10k", "hf_11_20k", 
"hf_21_50k", "hf_51_100k", "hf_m100k"), job = c("hf_l5k_job", 
"hf_5_10k_job", "hf_11_20k_job", "hf_21_50k_job", "hf_51_100k_job", 
"hf_m100k_job"), tot = c("hf_l5k_tot", "hf_5_10k_tot", "hf_11_20k_tot", 
"hf_21_50k_tot", "hf_51_100k_tot", "hf_m100k_tot")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Here is the code I have tried with a traditional for loop:

```
library(dplyr)

tot_function <- function(df, filter_tot, col_name1, col_name2) {
  # filter desired columns for all jobs
  filter_tot <- df %>% filter(col_name1=="1") %>% 
  summarise(col_name2 = n()) 
}

for (i in seq_along(hf_names3)) {
  tot_function(df3, hf_names3$tot[i], hf_names3$hf_names[i], hf_names3$job[i])

}
```

The expected results would be dataframes or vectors:

```
hf_l5k_jobs hf_l5_10k_jobs
10               193
```

but nothing is generated by this code as it looks at simple functions such as trim and runif.

Comment: Please create a *minimal* example for this as discussed in the instructions at the top of the [tag:r] tag page.   Surely this problem can be illustrated in fewer than 37 columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need to overcomplicate this. You can take names from `hf_names`, subset that column from `df3` and count the number of 1's in that column.

```
sapply(hf_names$hf_names, function(x) sum(df3[[x]] == 1))

#    hf_l5k   hf_5_10k  hf_11_20k  hf_21_50k hf_51_100k   hf_m100k 
#         0          2          0          0          0          0
```

If you prefer `tidyverse` you can change `sapply` to `map.*` variations

```
purrr::map_int(hf_names$hf_names, ~sum(df3[[.]] == 1))
```